# Modify MySQL database id numbers to be all odd or all even

Tags: mysql

I currently have two separate MySQL databases, one for a UK based website, and the other for an IE based website.
I have set up a multi-store system on the actual site so that everything can be managed from one admin interface, but now I need to merge the data from the two original databases. I need to modify things like customer id, address book id, order id, customer id so that they are not duplicated.

One option would be to modify, for instance, the customer id for database two so that they follow on from the last id of database one, but this isn't favourable as old customers from db2 are going to be numbered higher than new customers from db1.

My preferred option would be to run some commands on each of the original databases so that in db 1, all id numbers become odd, and on db2, all id numbers become even.

As an example, this is the structure of one table

```
CREATE TABLE `address_book` (
`address_book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entry_gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`entry_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`entry_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`entry_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entry_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And example content in db1 is

```
INSERT INTO `address_book` (`address_book_id`, `customers_id`, `entry_gender`, `entry_company`, `entry_firstname`, `entry_lastname`, `entry_street_address`, `entry_suburb`, `entry_postcode`, `entry_city`, `entry_state`, `entry_country_id`, `entry_zone_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User1', '1 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 369),
(2, 2, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User2', '2 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 197),
(3, 3, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User3', '3 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 235);
```

example content in db2 is

```
INSERT INTO `address_book` (`address_book_id`, `customers_id`, `entry_gender`, `entry_company`, `entry_firstname`, `entry_lastname`, `entry_street_address`, `entry_suburb`, `entry_postcode`, `entry_city`, `entry_state`, `entry_country_id`, `entry_zone_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'm', '', 'Site2', 'User1', '10 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 369),
(2, 2, 'm', '', 'Site2', 'User2', '20 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 197),
(3, 3, 'm', '', 'Site2', 'User3', '30 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 235);
```

Desired result from modification query would be to end up with content like this

```
INSERT INTO `address_book` (`address_book_id`, `customers_id`, `entry_gender`, `entry_company`, `entry_firstname`, `entry_lastname`, `entry_street_address`, `entry_suburb`, `entry_postcode`, `entry_city`, `entry_state`, `entry_country_id`, `entry_zone_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User1', '1 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 369),
(3, 3, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User2', '2 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 197),
(5, 5, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User3', '3 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 235);

INSERT INTO `address_book` (`address_book_id`, `customers_id`, `entry_gender`, `entry_company`, `entry_firstname`, `entry_lastname`, `entry_street_address`, `entry_suburb`, `entry_postcode`, `entry_city`, `entry_state`, `entry_country_id`, `entry_zone_id`) VALUES
(2, 2, 'm', '', 'Site2', 'User1', '10 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 369),
(4, 4, 'm', '', 'Site2', 'User2', '20 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 197),
(6, 6, 'm', '', 'Site2', 'User3', '30 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 235);
```

which would then allow me to import both sets of data without any duplicated id numbers, and it would allow the latest entries from both original databases to have newer id numbers.

One thing to note is that these id numbers are not necessarily sequential. There can be gaps in the order due to old/spam accounts being deleted. I don't mind if the end result doesn't retain these gaps in id numbers, in fact it would be preferable if it didn't, but not a deal breaker if that can't be done.

Is this possible without totally messing up the data?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time and resources, but this will be one heck of a task depending on the size of the database and the number of relations being migrated. A simpler option might be to change the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` id for each of the tables to something higher (like 100000 and 100001) and ensure the stepping is set to `2` 

Comment: It is better to divide not to "even"-"odd" but to "from 1"-"from maxvalue/2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simple Math, but it could take some time to process, depending on the number

Also you didn't mention any related table, where you also have to apply the algorithm

If you have for all linked tables a foreign Key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` it will automatically update all ids, but that sadly will not work with MyIsam

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `address_book` (
> `address_book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
> `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `entry_gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
> `entry_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
> `entry_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
> `entry_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `entry_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `address_book` (`address_book_id`, `customers_id`, `entry_gender`, `entry_company`, `entry_firstname`, `entry_lastname`, `entry_street_address`, `entry_suburb`, `entry_postcode`, `entry_city`, `entry_state`, `entry_country_id`, `entry_zone_id`) VALUES
> (1, 1, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User1', '1 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 369),
> (2, 2, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User2', '2 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 197),
> (3, 3, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User3', '3 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 235);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE address_book SET address_book_id = (address_book_id - 1) * 2  + 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM address_book
> ```
>
> ```
> address_book_id | customers_id | entry_gender | entry_company | entry_firstname | entry_lastname | entry_street_address | entry_suburb | entry_postcode | entry_city | entry_state | entry_country_id | entry_zone_id
> --------------: | -----------: | :----------- | :------------ | :-------------- | :------------- | :------------------- | :----------- | :------------- | :--------- | :---------- | ---------------: | ------------:
>               1 |            1 | m            |               | Site1           | User1          | 1 Any Street         | Any Town     | ANO1TH         | Any County |             |              222 |           369
>               3 |            2 | m            |               | Site1           | User2          | 2 Any Street         | Any Town     | ANO1TH         | Any County |             |              222 |           197
>               5 |            3 | m            |               | Site1           | User3          | 3 Any Street         | Any Town     | ANO1TH         | Any County |             |              222 |           235
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `address_book2` (
> `address_book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
> `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `entry_gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
> `entry_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
> `entry_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
> `entry_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
> `entry_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `entry_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `address_book2` (`address_book_id`, `customers_id`, `entry_gender`, `entry_company`, `entry_firstname`, `entry_lastname`, `entry_street_address`, `entry_suburb`, `entry_postcode`, `entry_city`, `entry_state`, `entry_country_id`, `entry_zone_id`) VALUES
> (1, 1, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User1', '1 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 369),
> (2, 2, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User2', '2 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 197),
> (3, 3, 'm', '', 'Site1', 'User3', '3 Any Street', 'Any Town', 'ANO1TH', 'Any County', '', 222, 235);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE address_book2 SET address_book_id = address_book_id * 2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM address_book2
> ```
>
> ```
> address_book_id | customers_id | entry_gender | entry_company | entry_firstname | entry_lastname | entry_street_address | entry_suburb | entry_postcode | entry_city | entry_state | entry_country_id | entry_zone_id
> --------------: | -----------: | :----------- | :------------ | :-------------- | :------------- | :------------------- | :----------- | :------------- | :--------- | :---------- | ---------------: | ------------:
>               2 |            1 | m            |               | Site1           | User1          | 1 Any Street         | Any Town     | ANO1TH         | Any County |             |              222 |           369
>               4 |            2 | m            |               | Site1           | User2          | 2 Any Street         | Any Town     | ANO1TH         | Any County |             |              222 |           197
>               6 |            3 | m            |               | Site1           | User3          | 3 Any Street         | Any Town     | ANO1TH         | Any County |             |              222 |           235
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=449bb60ebe3485d846d66e291130ff1e)*

Comment: There are at least a dozen tables where the customer id is used, so the same will have to be carried out on every one.
To reduce the number of updates, I will be running a process to archive all orders older than 12 months to csv files, and remove any customer accounts where they have not logged in for at least a year.

Comment: no usually you have a foreign key with ON UPDATE CASCADE, all linked tables will update the id automatocally

Comment: I added a related table here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d27efd1e4f3038645c464a2e47755f80.
customers_default_address_id in table customers is the same as address_book_id in table address_book. customers_id should be the same in table customers and table address_book. 
Can you give an example of how ON UPDATE CASCADE would work, then I can do some testing with more tables to ensure I understand the process fully before doing it on the real data.
Thank you :)

Comment: On UPDATE only works on innodb and not on myisam  see example at the end https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4610979711d1587301fa0f91a172faf

Comment: I don't have any issues with converting the tables to innodb rather than myisam. A new installation of the software uses innodb by default anyway. The tables using myisam are historical.

Comment: the you can use the example i posted at the end, see that the custmer table gest update botton up, That is why the update has a DESC ORDER